# slideToggle navbar again when click on list item link while .main-menu has class "open"

Tags: jquery

I use this jQuery code for Mobile menu toggle and adding class open, which works good

```
$('#menu-right-icon').click(function(){
var mainmenu = ".side-header nav.main-menu"
    $("#navbar").slideToggle(function() { 
        if ($(mainmenu).is(":visible")) {
            $(".main-menu").addClass("open");
        } else {
            $(".main-menu").removeClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

however after that I want to achieve to slideToggle navbar again when click on list item link while .main-menu has class "open" , but this solution does not work , probably because the class "open" can not be used outside the function where it is assigned

```
$('.side-header nav.main-menu.open li a').click(function(){
       $("#navbar").slideToggle();
       $(".main-menu").removeClass("open");
})
```

In this case, works good, but in the first if statement I added addClass, slideToggle and removeClass, but this is not the best solution, is there a more elegant solution?

```
$('#menu-right-icon').click(function(){
var mainmenu = ".side-header nav.main-menu"
    $("#navbar").slideToggle(function() { 
        if ($(mainmenu).is(":visible")) {
            $(".main-menu").addClass("open");
            $('.main-menu.open li a').click(function(){
                $("#navbar").slideToggle();
                $(".main-menu").removeClass("open");
            })
        } else {
            $(".main-menu").removeClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works good

```
$('#menu-right-icon').click(function(){
$("nav.main-menu").toggleClass("open");

$('.main-menu.open ul li a').click(function() {
    $("nav.main-menu").removeClass("open");
});
```

})